# Index of winning player in a game

Tags: algorithm, recursion, number-theory

`N` players play a game. They stand in a way such that they form a regular `N`-gon. Players are numbered from `1` to `N`. The players throw boomerangs in clockwise order, in turns. At first player `1` throws a boomerang through the center of the polygon. If `N` is even, then the boomerang hits the player on the opposite side, and the player who got hit leaves the game. If `N` is odd then the opposite point has no player, so the boomerang flies back to the player who threw it and hits him, making him leave the game. After a player leaves, the game continues with `N-1` players in the same way (i.e. they again make a regular `(N-1)`-gon). The player who's clockwisely closest to the last player who moved, has the turn now.

The game continues until only one player is left. Is there any closed form expression for the index of the winning player in terms of `N`? Or any fast (logarithmic or less) approach to calculate the index?

If `f(N)` denotes the answer, then I figured out a trivial recursion that `f(2n+1)=f(2n)+1` since in the odd case, player `1` is out in the first move and then player `2` moves. But nothing for the even case. Thanks for any help.

First few values: `n --> f(n)`

`2 --> 1`

`3 --> 2`

`4 --> 4`

`5 --> 5`

`6 --> 1`

`7 --> 2`

`8 --> 3`

`9 --> 4`

`10 --> 5`

`11 --> 6`

`12 --> 8`

`13 --> 9`

`14 --> 11`

`15 --> 12`

`16 --> 14`

Comment: The other recursion:  if f(2n-1) >= n, f(2n)=f(2n-1)+2 (mod 2n).  Otherwise, f(2n)=f(2n)+1 (mod 2n).    It's easy to see this if you write down the survival times of each index as a permutation.

Comment: Find the expression for the zero crossings, and you have a closed form.  I think it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

The other recursion goes thusly:

if `f(2n-1) >= n`, `f(2n)=f(2n-1)+2 (mod 2n)`. 
Otherwise, `f(2n)=f(2n)+1 (mod 2n)`.

It's easy to see this if you write down the survival times of each index as a permutation.

Applying the recursion to the zero crossings, we find that the n_th zero-crossing is at `4^(n+2)/3`

In light of all this, here is the algorithm for finding the winner of the n_th game:

```
k <- floor((log(3)+log(n))/log(4))+2
m <- 4^(k+2)/3
if n < 2m: 
    f(n) <- (n-m+1)%n
otherwise: 
    f(n) <- (n+2-m+(n-2*m)/2)%n
```

First few values:   `1,1,2,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,11,12...`

`f(100)=15`, `f(1000)=818`, `f(10000)=4539`, `f(100000)=12619`, etc, etc

Comment: Would love to add this sequence to Sloane's.   There an email addr I can credit you with?